# Android Twitter4j Automatic updates

Tags: android, twitter, twitter4j

We are integrating twitter to my android application. 
We are using Twitter4j library and are able to read the tweets by gettimeline Apis.

Anyone aware of any APIs(From twitter or written in library) which will directly invoke a call back function in my application. 
My intention is to avoid periodic api calls in application.

Can anyone help?

Regards,
Dhanesh

Answer (score 1):

This can be done with the streaming API of twitter4j, no?

Otherwise using AlarmManager every 30 min or so would be a good solution. Or use cloud to device from google.